# Allowing the GIF animation to take place while running the TranslateTransition

Tags: java, javafx

I have a ImageNode that I am treating as my player sprite. Its image is a .gif file which imitates the walking animation:

[image]

However, I am handling the movement by adding a TranslateTransition to move the character. This is the code I use:

```
movementTransition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(0.5), playerNode);
    movementTransition.setByX(DIRECTION_MAGNITUDE * direction.getX());
    movementTransition.setByY(DIRECTION_MAGNITUDE * direction.getY());
    movementTransition.setCycleCount(1);
    movementTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
    movementTransition.play();
```

Now, the translation works perfectly, but the gif animation does not run when the translation runs. **So when the translation animation is in effect, the image appears static** How can I run both the gif animation and the translation animation?

Comment: Seems like maybe [ParallelTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/ParallelTransition.html).

Comment: You could also benefit from posting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have so far.

Comment: @Sedrick I doubt that  would work since gifs are automatically animated by `ImageView`...

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that they had to be broken down to individual images and then looped.

Comment: @Sedrick the ImageView has a .gif file so yeah fabian is correct.

Comment: You need to post a `MCVE`. I can't duplicate this problem. When I run the `gif`, it's still animated while moving.